# Open a ppt file from excel, loop through the presentation, and make separate presentations based on textbox value

Tags: excel, vba, loops, powerpoint

I have several ppt files I need to spilt into smaller files.
I am opening the ppt files from excel

Each file has a customer textbox. At each change in the customer textbox I'd like make ppt files based on the customer. Here's what I have so far I'm unsure about the lines that add the files to the new presentation. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
Sub differentpptfiles()


Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application

Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open("myfile.pptx")

Dim slide As PowerPoint.slide
Dim currentValue As String

For Each slide In pptPres.Slides
' Check the value of the text box
Dim textBoxValue As String
textBoxValue = slide.Shapes("Customer").TextFrame.TextRange.Text

' If the value of the text box has changed, create a new presentation
If textBoxValue <> currentValue Then
    ' Create a new PowerPoint presentation
    Dim newPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Set newPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add

    ' Add the slide to the new presentation
   ' newPres.Slides.AddSlide 1, ppLayoutTitle
' not sure what should go here




    ' Save the new presentation with a unique name
    newPres.SaveAs "C:\Users\name\Desktop\PowerPoint Loop\My Presentation " & currentValue & ".pptx"

    ' Close the new presentation
    newPres.Close

    ' Update the current value of the text box
    currentValue = textBoxValue
End If
Next slide



End Sub
```

Ive tried the posted code. I think where I need help is below the line

```
    ' Add the slide to the new presentation
```

Answer (score 0):

First copy the range [Slides.range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slides.range) you need to put in the new presentation to the clipboard like

```
pptPress.slides.range().copy
```

Then you paste it into the slides collection of the new presentation

```
newPress.slides.paste
```

[Slides.paste](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slides.paste)